# Patch error 2 while trying to fix keyboard in ubuntu

Tags: kernel, keyboard, patch

Recently I acquire an Asus Tuf Gaming A15, and installed Windows and Ubuntu. In Ubuntu the keyboard does't work so I searched and found this [ASUS TUF A15 2023 Keyboard Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470529/asus-tuf-a15-2023-keyboard-not-working) and i also found the complete patch https://lore.kernel.org/linux-acpi/20230518183920.93472-1-mario.limonciello@amd.com/
While doing the make -j 16 , the terminal gives me one error: **make [Makefile:2032: .] Error 2 and i don´t know how to solve the problem.

(sorry for my english)

Comment: "Error 2" is a file access error (permission). What's your current directory, what are the directory's ownership/permission, what's your userid? Do: `pwd;ls -ld .;id` [Edit] your question to add the results, do not use "Add comment". Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting