# I installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my Asus Tuf Gaming A15 laptop (2023), the keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my Asus Tuf Gaming A15 laptop (2023), the keyboard does not work, the drivers are all installed, checked through the command, everything is updated, all packages are updated, tried reinstalling does not help, installed using the on-screen keyboard

---

Nothing helped, the problem is that ubuntu perceives the laptop as a tablet, and it is probably necessary to write a patch for the Linux kernel, to define new chip sets of keyboards, or what else can be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASUS TUF A15 2023 Keyboard Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470529/asus-tuf-a15-2023-keyboard-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You need another linux kernel version. The keyboard is supposed to work with 5.15.0-56.

The kernel bug has been described [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217336).

Someone also stated, that the bug might be affected by GPU drivers, namely Nvidia.

Try to grab a live USB image with 22.04 (or even 20.04) and test (without installing) if the older kernels will work with your hardware.

Comment: Nothing helped, the problem is that ubuntu perceives the laptop as a tablet, and it is probably necessary to write a patch for the Linux kernel, to define new chip sets of keyboards, or what else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same model of laptop. There's been development in the past few weeks regarding this keyboard bug. To make it work in my machine, I had to install mainline kernel and use Kernel `6.4.9`. You can download mainline from here https://github.com/bkw777/mainline.

One thing to note though is I wasn't able to get Nvidia drivers to work (trying out `nvidia-driver-535-open`. Reason why I need `-open` is so I can connect to an eGPU.

Anyway, I hope this helps. Let me know if using a later kernel works.